# background image shows truncated in Edge only

Tags: css, image, background, truncated

Web page loads beautifully in Chrome, Firefox and even IE.  However, when it loads in Edge, the envelope icon in the last column of the report gets truncated.

The report is in a table, and the width of the table cell is not the issue (i.e., if I expand the width of the cell, the cell widens, but the image is still truncated in Edge).

Edge must not like the CSS for the button.  I'm hoping there's an easy fix to this (one that doesn't break it for the other browsers).

```
<td style="align: left;"> <input type="button" name="email" class="mybutton" onclick="return doFunction();" /></td>

input.mybutton {
        background-image: url(/images/email.png);
        background-size: 15px;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 25px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: background-size: contain; plase try to add these property

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Edge. Please put up a working snippet, including the image and check that it shows the problem so we can see it for ourselves. (Use the <> icon when you edit the question).

Comment: I tried to upload an image, but I received a "forbidden" error.  Somehow I was able to fix the problem.  I'm not sure how, as I think it was fixed by something that I tried somewhere in the middle, but the cached page was not showing it fixed yet.